# Getting the last Monday

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

I'm trying to get 12am of the Monday from the current week, so either today (if the day is Monday) or otherwise look backward for the past Monday.

I've got the following code but not sure where to go from here.

`Date date = new Date(); date.setDate(date.getDate()`

not sure what to do here

Comment: Your tags suggest that this is a JavaScript question, but your code snippet is not valid JavaScript... (in particular `Date date = ...` looks like Java)

Answer (score 0):

```
let day = new Date();  // Get current date
day.setDate(day.getDate() - (day.getDay() + 6));

console.log(day.getDay());  // is 1
```

Comment: *so either today (if the day is Monday)*

Comment: Get the Monday of the previous week

Answer (score 0):

The general approach will be something like this:

1. Get the current date. You've already got this with `const date = new Date();`
2. Check if the current date is a Monday. `date.getDay()` will give you a number from 0-6, corresponding to Sunday-Saturday.
3. If today is not a Monday, change the date to subtract enough days to get us to a Monday. `date.getDay()` will give you the number of days to get back to Sunday, and then we will need to move back another 6 days to get to the previous Monday: `date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay() - 6);`
4. Now that the date is definitely a Monday, change the time to be 12:00am: `date.setHours(00, 00, 00);`

Putting it all together:

```
const date = new Date();
if (date.getDay() !== 1) {
   date.setDate(date.getDate() - date.getDay() - 6);
}
date.setHours(00,00,00);
```